# Repalce the entire Django admin template

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to replace the entire Django admin template and work with my own. I searched a lot but i found only overriding template which can't satisficate my need.
 how i can replace the entire admin template  ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: @ hisham Thanks for reply, i dont think that can satisfy my need because some functions  in admin template can't be overrdided .i want to make a new template admin like https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/

Comment: You can try Grapelli https://grappelliproject.com/

Comment: @iMitwe, thanks i will try it